# Bash Script for calculate the memory of a application

Tags: linux, bash, memory, memory-management

I want a bash script which will calculate the amount of memory used by specific application or command.

Comment: Did you search for solutions? Did you check whether any existing tools solves your requirement? Post your efforts so far.

Comment: It's not clear why you need a whole `bash` script just for that.. You can use `ps` or `top` commands to find out that information..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps o rss= -p PID` will output the resident set size of the given process.

Use `size` instead of `rss` to get the code+data+stack size.

Answer (score 1):

possible way:

use `top` within terminal, then pipe the output into a file and get the line you need (grep)